# override deleted aws_secretsmanager_secret resource using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have some secret which is created using terraform , due to some mistake I had commented and applied tf so the reource marked for deletion, but now if I enable it and apply it is saying the resource is marked for deletion.

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "rotation-example" {
  name                = "mysecret"
description       ="sccretatexample"
   recovery_windows_in_days = 7
}
```

I can't change the name and create other resource, and  also I dont have access to aws console/cli . pls guide me how to create again or is it possible to use the old one by overriding

Comment: Hi, if you have commented the resource and applied tf, it will not mark resource for delete but it will destroy the resource. Or you just execute apply but didnt give yes to execute? But in later case, if you  uncommented/enable resource and execute it will not show resource is marked for deletion. One of case be somebody has change something in resource manually from console and thats why now Terraform wants to delete and recreate it. Please correct me if there is something wrong in my understanding.

Comment: I have commented the resouce in terraform and applied,   looks like secrete managers can be destoryed  only if the retenion days set to  zero during creation but in my case I have set to 7 days...

Answer (score 1):

As of now there is no functionality available to retrieve deleted secret using terraform. Check this open issue -
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/10259

But you can do it using some manual work but either you will require help from your AWS administrator or AWS access key should be having below permission.

```
To restore a secret and the metadata in the console, you must have these permissions:

secretsmanager:ListSecrets – Use to navigate to the secret you want to restore.

secretsmanager:RestoreSecret – Use to delete any versions still associated with the secret.
```

if AWS access key have above permission use below cmd to restore password.

```
aws secretsmanager restore-secret --secret-id mysecret
```

follow this AWS document to restore secret.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/manage_delete-restore-secret.html

once secret is restored you can use "terraform import" as below to updated you state file with existing secret details.

```
terraform import aws_secretsmanager_secret.rotation-example mysecret
```

In addition, if you want to create and delete secret frequently use  below.

```
recovery_windows_in_days = 0
```